# Android ListView with only a single row of a unique view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I already have a ListView with a custom adapter for a custom view, and I'd like to add one more view that will only ever appear once in the list.

If I only ever need a single row of a special view in my ListView, is there a way to add it without modifying my adapter to handle multiple view types?

Or perhaps a layout trick that can hold the item and scroll as if the view was actually in the ListView?

Comment: Add a layout above with the same visual disposition of your listview item with the same size.

Comment: @cyberlobe I just want a listview with typical list items and then a map at the top of the list that scrolls with the list items.

Comment: @cyberlobe No one of the list items is a map, the rest are typical list items.

Comment: if view above or below listview, you can add header or footer to listview.

Comment: @mustafasevgi does a header still scroll with the items or is it fixed to the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can use it by adding a headerView in listview
yourListView.addHeaderView(yourView);
```